# Is it necessary to end episodes when collision occurs in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have implemented q learning algorithm in which the agent tries to travel as far as possible. I am using instantaneous rewards and final episode reward as well. When agent collides, i am giving high collision reward in negative and I am not stopping the episode. Is it ok to do like this or the episode must be ended once the agent collides?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have defined a minimum reward threshold, if it drops below that I end the episode.

- Case 1: **End episode on invalid action**
  If you end the game before penalizing an invalid move there is no way for the network to understand that the move was invalid.
- Case 2: **End episode after N invalid action**
  This gives it room to take a few invalid actions before the episode ends. Its analogous to playing a game: you have N lives to beat the level or you lose the game
- Case 3: **Not ending the game at all after invalid actions**
  This may cause the agent to get lost in the environment sometimes only doing invalid actions, you need a good termination condition to stop the episode

Hope this helps

Comment: In case 3,  what if i give a very high negative reward to the agent  for every invalid action and let the episode run without stopping. Is it a good approach?

Comment: For training, your data should have more valid moves than invalid moves as you are trying to teach the network how to win not lose.If invalid_moves_data > valid_moves_data, what exactly do you want the network to learn?